# Exclude folders from caching

Tags: wordpress, nginx, plesk

In Plesk under *Additional nginx directives* I've added the following cache settings.

```
location ~* .(jpg|js|css)$ { #shortened
    etag on;
    if_modified_since exact;
    add_header Pragma "public";
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
}
```

But in the wp-admin I have rewrites on the url's of these type of files.
**How Do I exclude `wp-admin/*` and `wp-includes/*` from the block above?**

Bit of background, I run a WordPress multisite in a subfolder. so
`maildomain.com/wp-admin/stylesheet.css` is actually located in
`maildomain.com/wp/wp-admin/stylesheet.css`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to experiment with location parameter before caching directives, e.g.:

```
location ^~ /wp-admin/ {
}

location ~* .(jpg|js|css)$ { #shortened
etag on;
if_modified_since exact;
add_header Pragma "public";
add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
}
```

UPD. Yes, checked it on my test lab and got the 403 error. I guess empty section is not enough and some directives should be added explicitly.

Managed to add exclusion like the one below:

```
location ~* "^/(?!wp-admin/|wp-includes/).*\.(jpg|js|css)$" { #shortened
etag on;
if_modified_since exact;
add_header Pragma "public";
add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
}
```

Comment: That in itselfs breaks the whole wp-admin

Comment: Yes that worked. It only needs one small tweak to also exclude the wp-includes which is also under `/wp/`.  It needs to be `location ~* "^/(?!wp-admin/|wp-includes/).*\ `

Comment: That is great! )